# Is there any possible way to Moq object's ToString method?

Tags: c#, moq

Right, title quite says it all.

```
[TestMethod()]
void TestFunc()
{
    string r = "Hello World"
    var oMoq = new Mock<object>();
    oMoq.setup(o => o.ToString()).Returns(r);

    Assert.AreEqual(r, oMoq.Object.ToString());
}
```

Using Moq framework and the unit testing framework shipped with VS2012 (express)

*ninja edit, forgot to include the question...*
Is there a way to make this possible?

(I am not fully sure the above code will compile at all, did this top of my head having no access to VS2012 atm)

**update**
To be more clear about my case:

I had a list of Objects

```
var myList = new List<MyObj>();
```

I added two MyObj mocks to it:

```
var oMoq = new Mock<MyObj>();
oMoq.setup(o => o.ToString()).Returns(r);
myList.Add(oMoq.Object);
myList.Add(oMoq.Object);
```

I then used

```
string.Join(",", myList);
```

Which I would expected to produce

> Hello World,Hello World

But instead it returned

> MyNamespace.MyObjMoqThingProxy,MyNamespace.MyObjMoqThingProxy

**Update**

using

```
var o = new Mock<object>();
o.Setup(x => x.ToString()).Returns("Hello World");

Assert.AreEqual("Hello World", o.Object.ToString());
```

Yields `Castle.Proxies.ObjectProxy`

```
public class Test
{
    override public string ToString()
    {
        return "myTClass";
    }
}
/* snip */
var o = new Mock<Test>();
o.Setup(x => x.ToString()).Returns("Hello World");

Assert.AreEqual("Hello World", o.Object.ToString());
```

Yields `Hello World`

So, to answer my very first own question. Guess you can't mock a objects ToString() method if that class hasn't overriden ToString somehwere. It (Moq) will then use its own internal ToString() method. Bugger.

Comment: Why do you dump code and ask us whether it will compile or run? Open up Visual Studio and try for yourself. :-)

Comment: As `Object`'s `ToString()` method is virtual, I see no reason why not

Comment: @CodeCaster don't have it on this shabby laptop. And won't have it within a few hours and was busy with it yesterday but it didn't work as I expected. Had to write the question down else it would keep me busy in my head :-)

Comment: Understandable. :-) Next time you can perhaps try to [create a draft](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting) and only submit it later when required.

Comment: @CodeCaster Ahh, never seen that functionality. Good tip. Guess it is too late for this question now :-(

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work since [`Object.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx) is a virtual method that Moq can mock.

**Update**
Try `string.Join(",", myList.Select(o=>o.ToString()));`

Comment: I have update the answer ( still no access to VS). string.Join will need array of strings

Comment: Hmm, I would have expected it to use the objects ToString method. Even doing a thing like `string.Join<MyObj>(",", myList.ToArray());` did not help. Will try your Select statement this evening

Comment: let me know how it work. Just guessing - I think it does cast to string for each element in `myList` ....

Comment: Right, the case was with the Moq framework and not so much anything to do with the `string.Join` function. Moq has its own internal `ToString` method if the class being mocked hasn't overriden ToString anywhere in its hyrarchie

Answer (score -1):

One way to do this is to extract an interface for your object and explicitly declare the ToString() method on that interface, then mock the interface rather than the class and the setup will work

```
public interface IMyObj
{
    string ToString();
}

public class MyObj : IMyObj
...

var iMoq = new Mock<IMyObj>();
iMoq.setup(o => o.ToString()).Returns(r);
myList.Add(iMoq.Object);
myList.Add(iMoq.Object);
```

the only change to your implementation code would be to change the type of the List

```
var myList = new List<IMyObj>();
```

Comment: @esskar could you provide more details when you say isnt working?  in what way does it not work?